# How to update all items in an Array with Airbnb JavaScript Style?

Tags: javascript, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb, airbnb-js-styleguide

Let's say that we have an array like this:

```js
let list = [
  {
    name: '1',
    count: 0,
  },
  {
    name: '2',
    count: 10,
  },
  {
    name: '3',
    count: 18,
  },
];
```

Then how to update all items to increase `count` by 1?

Here comes several solutions, while **none of them** is quite satisfactory:

```js
/* no-restricted-syntax error, pass */
for (const item of list) {
  item.count += 1;
}


/* no-param-reassign error, pass */
list.forEach((item) => {
  item.count += 1;
});


/* 
  Object.assign is free to use without error
  but it against the intention of no-param-reassign
 */
list.forEach((item) => {
  Object.assign(item, { count: item.count + 1 });
});


/* 
  use Array.map() to replace the original array
  but it costs a lot when the item is large or the array has a large length
  also ugly code for such a tiny update
 */
list = list.map((item) => ({
  ...item,
  count: item.count + 1,
}));
```

If you have a better solution or consider `Array.map()` is good enough, please leave your opinion.

Thank you :)

Comment: why not? list = list.map(item => item.count++)

Comment: Are the rules such as `no-param-reassign` strict or personal preference? Because it sounds like you are trying to do just that. If strict, seems like `Array.map()` is the best solution.

Comment: @user1599011 It's strict. I want to improve my code style by a authoritative style guide (and I choose Airbnb JavaScript Style). It's helpful in most condition, but I think sometimes it's over-optimized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally use normal for loop to avoid Airbnb lint issue as follow:

```js
for (let index = 0; index < list.lenght; index++) {
    const item = list[index];
    if (item) {
        item.count += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that still break the "no-param-reassign" rule?

Comment: No, `no-param-reassign` rule only mentions that you cannot update the object/value passed as a function parameter, like in `forEach` function the item is a function parameter. Since here we are not using any function, we are not breaking `no-param-reassign` rule.

Comment: Gotcha! And in that case, this is the simplest, most straightforward choice.

Comment: Yes, simplest and straightforward, this is good for me. While I'm considering whether to overwrite `no-restricted-syntax` rule for this issue https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/2428

Comment: I submit an new issue about this problem and get some suggestions https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/2585

Comment: Doesn't this break the unary increment prohibition?